# Solution to open a windows server multiple GUI session for same user

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, automation, vnc, opencv

I am working on a Computer vision application. which launches an application on a remote server and navigates through GUI application to check if it's working fine.

How I do it now is I installed my code on a remote server and I RDP to this server and run it. As this process involves taking screenshots moving the mouse pointer interacting with the screen. only one application can be tested at a time.

I want to scale this to perform Multiple checks at the same time without creating multiple user accounts.

Is this possible to open multiple GUI sessions for same user and interact with each of them in a different manner. to put in short I need something which resembles a Docker with GUI.